# How to find corresponding point in rectified image using EMGU CV

Tags: opencv, emgucv, triangulation, stereo-3d

I am working with EMGU CV. I have a pair of rectified images from Bumblebee2 stereo vision camera. After finding coordinates of both the respective images, I am trying to find the corresponding points from the left image to right while taking left image as reference. How can I find it?[Left and right image with detected points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfMoh.png) Here are points detected from right and left images as below:

Left Image:

```
0-{X=384,9483, Y=149,7964}
1-{X=449,4588, Y=145,659}
2-{X=449,8427, Y=209,5965}
3-{X=393,903, Y=87,71234}
4-{X=366,9935, Y=57,17787}
5-{X=385,6826, Y=213,5658}
6-{X=393,8017, Y=41,57755}
7-{X=467,9185, Y=55,23401}
```

Right Image Points:

```
0-{X=261,4361, Y=149,7478}
1-{X=326,5302, Y=209,6012}
2-{X=325,55, Y=145,6009}
3-{X=262,6892, Y=213,5657}
4-{X=266,4678, Y=87,63588}
5-{X=239,4005, Y=57,10946}
6-{X=265,8781, Y=41,5235}
7-{X=339,6883, Y=55,14074}
```

As I am using rectified images so I have same epipolar line with very small difference between two images. For given reference images I can handle to find corresponding point with simple maths. But when I will have more number of points in same epipolar line then It will make some problem. So please suggest me some method to find corresponding point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the corresponding point you can use [block matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-matching_algorithm).